# jquery how to get available furthest element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have grid where green square is my .smFly , blue squares are elements avaible elements where I can move my .smFly class, I want add  `.css("border:1px solid blue;") to them;`

Grid looks like: http://scr.hu/14ow/ei43o

my code looks like:

```
var myElem = "smFly";
var myAvPos = function(myElem){

var elemsGrid = [[1,0][1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[1,6],[1,7],[1,8],[1,9],[2,0][2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5],[2,6],[2,7],[2,8],[2,9],[3,0][3,1],[3,2],[3,3],[3,4],[3,5],[3,6],[3,7],[3,8],[3,9],[4,0][4,1],[4,2],[4,3],[4,4],[4,5],[4,6],[4,7],[4,8],[4,9],[5,0][5,1],[5,2],[5,3],[5,4],[5,5],[5,6],[5,7],[5,8],[5,9],[6,0][6,1],[6,2],[6,3],[6,4],[6,5],[6,6],[6,7],[6,8],[6,9]];
```

// above is grid fields in two-dimensional array [x,y]

```
    if ($('.'+myElem+'> input').is(':checked')) {
        var fieldY = $('tbody').find('.'+myElem).parent().prop('className');
        var fieldX = $('.'+fieldY).parent().prop('className');
        fieldX = fieldX.substring(1);
        console.log(fieldX);

        var avPos = fieldX + 2; And here I dont know how to calculate new pos that is markered by blue color in screen.

    } else {
        alert("Check element first!");
    }

}
```

HTML looks like:

```
<tbody>
                <tr class="x1">
                    <td class="y0">
                        <label class="smFly">
                            <input type="checkbox">
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="y1">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="y2">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="y3">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="x2">
                    <td class="y0">
                        <label class="selected">
                            <input type="checkbox">
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="y1">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="y2">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="y3">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                        </label>
                    </td>
```

Any help? please.

Comment: What does console.log(fieldX); output?

Comment: @Jason console.log(fieldX) ; showing x1 - position where actually is my .smFly

Comment: You cannot do direct addition with a string then. You will have to take extract the number in this case 1. ParseInt it. Then add 2. And then attach the number to x.